# How to achieve speed more than 1000 msg/sec to SQS?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have the following code that sends a batch message to SQS.
My goal is to send `1000 msg/sec` in `while true` loop.

I have a bottleneck - select random ids from CSV file. How can I improve the algorithm to achieve the goal?

```
async def send_to_sqs(file_path, loop):
    ids = load_file_to_list(file_path)
    while True:
        messages = []
        for id in ids:
            message = {'Id': id}
            messages.append(message)

        for i in range(0, 10000, 10): #butch size is 10
            messages_batch = messages[i:i+10]

            entries = []
            for message in messages_batch:
                entries.append({'Id': str(message['Id']),
                'MessageBody': json.dumps(message)})
            await sqs.send_message_batch(QueueUrl=sqs_url, Entries=entries)


def load_file_to_list(file_path):
   with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
     reader = csv.reader(f)
     return list(reader)
```

Comment: Have you benchmarked it to find the bottleneck?  Have you observed how much CPU time the entire program needs when running compared to real time? Signing the requests and the HTTPS overhead can require significant CPU time.

Answer (score 4):

Why dont you use UUIDs? This is far more likely to be unique than random ID from a file you pre-created

To solve your code more directly, without taking a step back, I'd consider leaving the file open as persistent in the background, rather than opening it everytime you call your function.

Answer (score 2):

I would try gathering all of the possible random id's from your CSV file in memory before you start your while loop.  That way the loop does not have to open the file and get a random number.  You could then write a function that selects a random number from the list of random numbers held in memory.  This would speed things up a lot.